# How to return Hash FQL Query from Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, hash, facebook-fql, koala

I am new here and really new to Ruby so I will do my best to ask a good question. Basically I am trying to write an app that returns Facebook events a user has been invited to. Pretty simple. The issue is it keeps returning everything like this

```
[{"name"=>"SPB Presents An Evening With Demetri Martin"}], [{"name"=>"Say \"Pi\" to Passover!"}]
```

I just want the value of the key. I've tried to use ["name"] and look at basic Ruby tutorial but I got a myriad of errors each time.

Here is my code:

HomeController:

```
def index
if session["fb_access_token"].present?
    @fql = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session["fb_access_token"])
    @invites = @fql.fql_query("SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()")
end

def names(eid)
if session["fb_access_token"].present?
    @fql = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session["fb_access_token"])
    @fql.fql_query("SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid = #{eid}")
end
end
```

Home View

```
<% if @invites %>
        <% for invite in @invites %>
                <p><%=h names(h invite["eid"])%></p>
<% end >
<% end >
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help! Also if anyone has a better way to build this so I don't have to do so much work in the views or how to do a better for each loop in the controller, that'd be nice too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem if anyone is curious. The fql query stores everything in an array with one hash of "location" in it, so each time I displayed the query it displayed the array. This was my fix:

```
def names(eid)
  if session["fb_access_token"].present?
  @fql = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session["fb_access_token"])
  @hashmap = @fql.fql_query("SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid = #{eid}")
  @name = @hashmap[0]["name"]
```

Now I pull the first object in the array at index 0 and the use the key "name." Worked like a charm!